# How to start an rpyc server?

Tags: python, rpyc

I recently installed rpyc on my Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual machine using:

```
pip install rpyc
```

i cannot find the file which can be used to start the server. I have looked in many places but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply `rpyc_classic.py` from the comand line:

```
$ rpyc_classic.py 
INFO:SLAVE/18812:server started on [0.0.0.0]:18812
```

Then connect:

```
from rpyc import classic

c = classic.connect("0.0.0.0",port=18812)

print(c.modules.sys.platform)
linux
```

You will see the connection in your shell:

```
INFO:SLAVE/18812:accepted 127.0.0.1:58217
INFO:SLAVE/18812:welcome [127.0.0.1]:58217
```

The example is in the [pypi documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpyc/3.3.0)